# setState from function not updating property

Tags: reactjs

I have a button assigned to a function that is supposed to update the footer property after being clicked but it isn't changing the footer text. It is however executing the console log statement. I have a feeling that it's related to 'this' but I don't know enough on what to Google to fix it.

I'm trying to learn Reactjs, specifically more about states and timeouts.\ I have a simple JS fiddle of what is going on here:

https://jsfiddle.net/dwekg5aq/2/

The footer function:

```
  updateFooter = () => {
    //alert("clicked");
    this.setState = {
      footer: "new footer text from button!"
    }
    console.log("updateFooter func fired.")
    console.log(this.state)
  }
```

EDIT: don't assign your states in a function :/

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#using-state-correctly need to call `setState`, not assign to it

Comment: isn't it this.setState({footer: "new footer text"}) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setState` is a function. You need to call it like this:

```
this.setState ({
   footer: "new footer text from button!"
});
```

From the React documentation:

> You can update [different elements from your state] independently with
>   separate setState() calls.

You don't assign the result of`setState` to anything, you just call it since it's a React method from your class.

Instead of

```
this.setState = ({
  footer: "new footer text from button!"
});
```

You need to just call it and let React manage it for you:

```
this.setState ({
  footer: "new footer text from button!"
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `setState()`. Also if you want to log the updated state immediately after running `setState()`, `setState()` takes an optional second callback argument. 
Using the callback ensures you get the most up to date version of state. If you simply log state on the next line, the updated changes won't be seen.

`this.setState({ footer: "new footer text from button!" }, () => { console.log(this.state) })`

Read more here: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate

Hope it helps